# Uniform convergence on compact sets.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I think I missed something in this question because it asks me to use compactness in my proof, but I did none of that…

> Let $K \subset M$ be compact in $(M,d)$. Assume $f_n,g_n \in C(K,\Bbb R)$ for each $n \in \Bbb N$ with $f_n \to f$ and $g_n \to g $ uniformly on $K$. Prove $f_ng_n \to fg$ uniformly on $K$ as well.

Here is what I wrote,

\begin{align}
\|  f_ng_n - fg\|_{\infty} &\leq \| f_n - f\|_\infty \| g_n - g\|_\infty +\| f_n - f\|_\infty \| g\|_\infty + \| f\|_\infty \| g_n - g\|_\infty \\
&\to 0 + 0\|g \|_\infty + 0\|f\|_\infty \\
&= 0.
\end{align}

I am guessing compactness is used so that $\| g \|_\infty < \infty$ and then Extreme Value Theorem? I am not entirely sure. It's awfully vague to me.

> Provide a counterexample with $f_n,g_n: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ to show $f_ng_n$ need not converge uniformly if $K$ is not compact.

I am not sure if there is a typo, but doesn't this mean I can take any non-uniformly convergent function $f_n$ and call $g_n = 1$ to be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need compactness to get$\|f\|_\infty < \infty$ and $\|g\|_\infty < \infty$.

Presumably the second part of the question meant to include the assumptions
$f_n, g_n \in C(K,\mathbb R)$ and $f_n \to f$ uniformly and $g_n \to g$ uniformly.
The counterexample should have $f$ and/or $g$ unbounded.